# Subscripting more than one symbol in python

Tags: python, plot, subscript

I'm creating a graph with ticks replaced by variable names. I would like the names to match what I have written in other parts of the document. The names are DAT with subscript Y1 to Y8. I've used the usual dollar sign:

```
period=["$DAT_Y1$",... ,"$DAT_Y8$"]
```

but it only puts the "Y" in the subscript.

How do I mark that all the characters after "_" should be in subscript?

Thank you!

Edited as requested:
The simplified (removed legends, colours etc) code is:

```
x=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
VA=[93.54,95.62,85.76,78.55,86.13,71.78,78.19,66.91]
plt.plot(x, VA)

period=["$DAT_Y1$", "$DAT_Y2$", "$DAT_Y3$","$DAT_Y4$","$DAT_Y5$","$DAT_Y6$","$DAT_Y7$","$DAT_Y8$"]
plt.xticks(x, period)
```

However, I don't have any problems with the rest of the code. The graph is produced in the exact way I'd like it to look, the only problem is that the subscript takes one character only, instead of two as I would like.

Comment: Could you add some code that shows what are you trying to do? This sound like a task doable trough regular expressions, but I'd like to know what exactly are you trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For subscripts you should make sure the text are inside the curly `{}` braces.

Example:

```
period=["DAT$_{Y1}$"]
```

Add the curly braces for all your texts and it should work!

See the sub-section "Subscripts and Superscripts" [here!!](http://matplotlib.org/users/mathtext.html) See the {i=0} example.